# OWIN OAuth invalid grant error in Windows Service vs. Console App

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api, katana, topshelf

I have a Web API using OWIN for OAuth, running in Katana/TopShelf.

When I install the Web API as a Windows Service, everything responds correctly, except a POST via resource owner flow (grant_type=password, username=x, password=y) returns 400 Bad Request (invalid_grant).

The exact same Web API, running in the same folder, except this time running in Command Line mode, using the exact same request from the same remote address, is successful.

The only delta is whether I run the .exe file directly in Console mode or I install and start it as a Windows Service.

I have to think this is a conflict at the network level but Windows Service is just acting as a thin host around the same HttpListener based host.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we see an issue like this with Topshelf it is almost always permission related. There's some resource that you have rights to but the service user doesn't. Are there resources on disk the service accesses or something similar?

Comment: The Windows Service is logged in as the same admin user I run the executable in console mode, when I install it as a service, but it's worth looking into. Katana OAuth may be internally dumping tokens to disk after encryption. Will have to check its source code.